# OOD using PHP versus Functional service-based Architecture

Tags: php, mysql, oop, search

I have always been building my application architecture predominantly using functional paradigms, specifically for the parts/modules which I build from scratch. Now, I am trying out OOD as well. In a PHP, MySQL, IdiORM based app for tracking music tracks information; my next step is to build the search functionality, where-in I plan to create a class, if it is the right way to go. I am well familiar with general theoretical OOP concepts like inheritance, polymorphism and the likes.

In my typical workflow, as it has been over the last few years, I would create a file in includes directory called say search.inc.php, implement functions like:

```
function search_by_artist($artist_name){
...
} 
function search_by_track($track_name){
...
}
```

and then code this as a service which returns JSON based on fetch results from the database and the `WHERE` clause is created using POSTed values from a form.

My question is that in this context, does it make sense to move these implementations to a class called Search. If so, what would an instance of this class represent logically ?
Am sorry for asking a naive question, but since most of my background has been with functional PHP and prototypal inheritance in JavaScript, am not very familiar with how orthodox OOD applies here. Further, will it be advisable to turn add.inc.php or in general, all of the CRUD service files into classes ?

*In general, in what kind of scenario should a functional service-based architecture be preferred and when is it better to use OOD ?*

Comment: If it works do not fix it. If your not knowledgeable on object oriented programming then leave production as-is and learn on development

Comment: @DarylGill Yes. Definitely ! The production is fine, as works perfectly as I have coded most of this from scratch. I wish to expand my horizons, so I am working on a local copy to understand the nuances of OOD, for future projects so that I can use it when it makes the result more effective. :)

Comment: Object oriented programming can be an absolute star if setup correctly. Makes it organized and cleaner code. It's up to the developer to understand when to implement extended, abstract classes ontop of the current deployment

Answer (score 3):

One big thing that OOP can improve in an application is decoupling of different parts. Using functions (note that I'm not saying *functional code*), your search functions probably look something like this:

```
function search_by_artist($artist_name) {
    global $db;
    $db->query(...)
    ...
}
```

The function is hardcoded to rely on a specific database connection.

Using OOP, you can decouple this:

```
class Search {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function byArtist($name) {
        $this->db->query(...);
        ...
    }

}
```

Having an object constructor is a powerful thing. The constructor *must* run before any of the other methods in the class are run, and thereby allows you to impose certain preconditions. Unless you get a valid `Database` instance at object construction time, none of the class methods will ever be able to run. That means none of the class methods need to care about a database connection, they can simply assume there is one available at `$this->db`. How exactly it gets there is the constructor's job in conjunction with the code calling it. You have created a seam in your codebase at which you can flexibly pass different database instances, while at the same time creating the guarantee that a database instance will be available.

In actual *functional* code, the function should look like this:

```
function search_by_artist(Database $db, $name) {
    ...
}
```

A function should purely act on its input and return defined output, it should not rely on implicit environment variables or produce side effects. The difference to OOP is that you don't have to pass the `$db` instance to every function individually, you can instantiate the object once with the dependency and then pass it around as one encapsulated package.

Comment: Note that the database is only a very low-hanging fruit example. If you rigorously apply this OO design with dependency injection to everything, you'll end up with an extremely modular app which you can put together in various ways in various scenarios. Pure functional programming can do the same thing, but dealing with passing all required parameters to all functions can be quite a hassle in PHP. Functional languages like Haskell are a lot better suited for passing such dependencies and state around in a functional manner.

Comment: I get the idea now for a general project using mysqli interface or something. However, as I am analyzing this as a contender for OOD; I am using IdiORM and hence, I need not pass any DB connection around. As an example, ORM::for_table()->find_array() is available in whole of the environment and hence can be accessed in all the functions.

Comment: See my take on static method calls here: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/). Having `ORM::*` available everywhere isn't any better than `global $db`.

Comment: Hm..actually, _functional_ programming concept is about _no-state_ (so, there's no state in common sense if talking about pure functional concept)

Comment: @AlmaDo Sure, the functions themselves and the environment is stateless (as much as possible). But every application needs state in some form or another. In functional programming that state is simply *passed around* as parameters and return values. The state is altered by being passed through stateless functions. That's why in pure functional languages like Haskell you're mostly dealing with very complex type declarations, since you need to encapsulate all that state in more complex types.